# couchbase replication across data center

Tags: couchbase

Let's say I'm setting up couchbase with a bucket replicating across N number of data centers.
Can I write documents into bucket in each data center and use replication, so each bucket in each data center will contain all documents in all data centers ?

Comment: This is how cross data center replication works in Couchbase 2.0.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. As long as you create a replication to each data center this will work. You could for example set up bi-directional replication as follows:

(Data Center A) <-- rep 1 --> (Data Center B) <-- rep 2 --> (Data Center C)

or any other combination of replications as long as there is a path to each data center through those replications.

See http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-admin-tasks-xdcr.html for more information.